# ERROR creating Maven project in Eclipse due to Proxy/Intranet restriction

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, proxy

Has anyone experienced this before where you're working in an intranet-connected environment where some sites are restricted.
Where do I add the proxy settings, in Eclipse?

Here?

[image]

or Here?
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

```
<!-- proxies
| This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
| Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
| specification in this list marked as active will be used.
|-->
<proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    <proxy>
        <id>optional</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username>proxyuser</</username>
        <password>proxypass</password>
        <host>proxy.host.net</host>
        <port>80</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->
</proxies>
```

I cant use pom.xml to download maven dependencies because Eclipse/Maven can't seem to download the necessary files which Im suspecting is due to intranet proxy settings.

Comment: Maven is doing the downloading of the dependencies for Eclipse, so you should configure the proxy there -- in settings.xml.